# Creating parent/child relationships among UIViewControllers in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, parent-child

I'm a bit uncertain about when and why we should/must establish parent-child relationships between our `UIViewController` objects. Consider an app like Twitter with a 4-section tab bar. Let's assume each section root `UIViewController` (among the 4) is a child of a parent container and each `UIViewController` within that section is a child of its section view controller. And that makes perfect sense.

But in Twitter, for example, each section may have its own `UINavigationController` and, therefore, its own independent navigation stack. And, therefore, there can exist a scenario where the user is viewing, for example, the same exact tweet simultaneously in two separate sections. Is that tweet, in those instances, two separate children to two different parents?

**Apple:**

> A UINavigationController object supports navigation through a
>   hierarchical data set. A navigation interface presents one child view
>   controller at a time.

Does this mean that the `UINavigationController` creates its own parent-child relationships when pushing view controllers onto its stack or should this be done manually when a new view controller is pushed? And, in the Twitter example, how necessary is it to have a parent-child relationship in a `UINavigationController` stack given the possible overlap?

And if somebody could point me to an article/video/etc about parent-child relationships in iOS, their significance, pitfalls, dos and don'ts, I'd really appreciate it, since I can't find any myself.

Comment: I think your question is a gray-zone for being off-topic, falling under the category of asking for a tutorial, and the rest of your questions may or may not already been answered. I am not sure However, I answered your question, you should avoid these kind of questions in the future and instead present a problem , what you have tried, what is failing etc. GL.

Comment: Respectfully, SO is not just for explicit problems or when things fail. I'm perfectly fine with people posing specific questions about broad concepts, especially important ones like this where literature is sparse, because they generally have more utility than questions with granular specificity. IMHO, requiring developers to devote their time to doing things until they break should generally be avoided. I appreciate your answer, however!

Comment: I agree with you partly, as I said, I am not sure since you specifically asked several questions in the same post I think this might be valid and thats why I answered. However, asking for directions to third party sites and guides falls under the category Off-topic, even if it would help people as you say, links and third party sites are not guaranteed to always work and be up, and the answers/solutions should show up here on SO. Thats why I answered with the solution, and included the link in my answer, but my answer is still understandable and valid without the links :)

Comment: I have elaborated the answer so you can grasp everything easier. And provided you with some more guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is that tweet, in those instances, two separate children to two
>   different parents?".

It depends on what you mean by "**Tweet**". "**Tweet**" can be the same object, **or** two different objects with the same visual content. Both is possible, and there are no "best practices", its all up to your use-case and what you want to achieve.

If one object is presented on the screen, inside a UITableView (as in Twitter app), that doesnt make the UITableView or the UIViewController the objects "parent".

As for the Twitter app, (I'm not a user of the app) , I would guess it's the same object , showcased in two different places.

How is this possible? [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) **<--** This is actually the solution to your problems.

> Does this mean that the UINavigationController creates its own
>   parent-child relationships when pushing view controllers onto its
>   stack

Yes -

> The object in the viewController parameter becomes the top view controller on the navigation stack. Pushing a view controller causes its view to be embedded in the navigation interface. If the animated parameter is YES, the view is animated into position; otherwise, the view is simply displayed in its final location.
>   In addition to displaying the view associated with the new view controller at the top of the stack, this method also updates the navigation bar and tool bar accordingly. For information on how the navigation bar is updated, see Updating the Navigation Bar.

Quote taken from : [Apple documentations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller?language=objc)

> or should this be done manually when a new view controller is
>
> > pushed?

No

> And, in the Twitter example, how necessary is it to have a
>   parent-child relationship in a UINavigationController stack given the
>   possible overlap?

Read about [MVC structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html), and stop mixing UIViewControllers-Navigationcontrollers with objects and content you want to show in the UI. I think your issue is that you have not grasped [how object oriented language works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbXsrHGhBAU), or atleast how to implement it in iOS.

Edit:
Updating your object, should also update where it is presented in your app, in every UIViewController, (as I understand from what you want to achieve) . This is where CoreData and [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) comes in to the picture.

> In addition, fetched results controllers: Optionally monitor changes
>   to objects in the associated managed object context, and report
>   changes in the results set to its delegate (see The Controller’s
>   Delegate).

There are also many [tutorials](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-observe-a-managed-object-context/) if you need to handle [this manually](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontextobjectsdidchangenotification) without the help of an NSFetchedResultsController, that can be done also. Just search and Google will provide.